# How to make a global list in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have *three windows forms* in my project, and I have an *object class*. How can I make a list of those objects that will be available for all *three forms* to use?

Comment: A static class, for instace?

Comment: Make the list as  static property of a class. It will be available for all the forms.

Comment: And where should I define the list in my project?

Comment: @Priyank so I need to make a list of those object in the same class?

Comment: No you can make the list any where.But you will assign that list to the static property. And through that property you can use that list any where in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change the access modifier
   In Form2 Set the access modifier for the control / field public
   Anywhere Form1.

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2();
   f.ShowDialog();
   this.textBox1.Text = f.textBox1.Text;
   ```

   - The fastest to implement and convenient way
   - Contrary to all the basics of OOP
   - The transmission of only a later form of an earlier
   - Form f only shown using ShowDialog (), ie in the first form control returns only the second closing. Avoid this by maintaining a link to the second form in the first form
2. Use of public property / method. The method is very similar to the first
   In Form2 class defines a property (or method).

   In Form2 class defines a property (or method)

   ```
   public string Data
   {
       get
       {
           return textBox1.Text;
       }
   }
   ```

   Anywhere in Form1

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2();
   f.ShowDialog();
   this.textBox1.Text = f.Data;
   ```

   - Does not contradict all the basics of OOP
   - Cons same
3. Data transfer to the constructor Form2.
   Change the constructor Form2

   ```
   public Form2(string data)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.data = data;
   }
   string data;
   ```

   And create a shape anywhere Form1 as follows:

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2(this.textBox1.Text);
   f.ShowDialog();
   ```
4. To send a link to constructor.
   Change the constructor Form2.

   ```
   public Form2(Form1 f1)
   {
       InitializeComponent();    
       string s = f1.textBox1.Text;
   }
   ```

   And create a shape anywhere Form1 so that pass it a reference to the first form

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2(this);
   f.ShowDialog();
   ```

   - Access to all open fields / functions of the first form
   - Data transfer is possible in both directions
   - Violates the PLO
5. Use the property 'parent'.
   When you create a second form sets the owner

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2();
   f.Owner = this;
   f.ShowDialog();
   ```

   In the second, we determine the owner

   ```
   Form1 main = this.Owner as Form1;
   if(main != null)
   {
       string s = main.textBox1.Text;
       main.textBox1.Text = "OK";
   }
   ```

   - Access to all open fields / functions of the first form
   - Data transfer is possible in both directions
   - Do not violate the PLO
6. Use a separate class.
   Create a separate class, better static, mainly namespace, ie for example in the Program.cs file

   ```
   static class Data
   {
       public static string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   His public properties / methods are available from any form.

   ```
   Data.Value = "111";
   ```

   - The most convenient way when data is actively used in several forms.
7. Transfer method in the constructor.
   Create delegate

   ```
   public delegate void MyDelegate(string data);
   ```

   In Form1, create a method that will handle the received data

   ```
   void func(string param)
   {
       //Process
   }
   ```

   Create a second form as follows:

   ```
   Form2 f = new Form2(new MyDelegate(GetData));
   f.ShowDialog();
   ```

   Change constructor of second form to accept a delegate

   ```
   MyDelegate d;
   public Form2(MyDelegate sender)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       d= sender;
   }
   ```

   And at any moment send data

   ```
   d(textBox1.Text);
   ```
8. Creating a separate class with a delegate.
   In main namespace create separate class

   ```
   public static class Data
   {
       public delegate void MyEvent(string data);
       public static MyEvent EventHandler;
   }
   ```

   In the first form, add a handler

   ```
   void func(string param)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(param);
   }
   ```

   and initialize the EventHandler

   ```
   Data.EventHandler = new Data.MyEvent(func);
   ```

   Create a second form in the usual way and then call it from

   ```
   Data.EventHandler(textBox1.Text);
   ```

   - The most flexible way to transfer data
   - Difficult to implement and understand

Comment: I updated Answer. Sorry for my English =)

Comment: the sixth option seems the easiest I think :)

Answer (score 5):

You could create a class containing an instance of your object:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public static List<string> MyList {get; set}
}
```

Then you can access it from your form

```
MyClass.MyList = new List<string>();
```

Obviously string will be replaced with the name of your object.

Comment: Could I just create this list in one of the existent forms and make it static? A form is also considered a class, as far as I know :D

Comment: I'd probably not - creating it in a class separates it from your forms, so, for instance if you deleted one of your forms then it wouldn't affect the rest.

Comment: @TheAdnan: You should not accept first answer. dima_horror's answer is a lot better. This answer promotes public field which is wrong. It should be public getter/setter instead.

Comment: but it technically would work then? I just need it for now to work, I will later make it more efficient :)

Comment: @Peri I'm new here so I'm still trying to figure things out :)

Comment: Thanks Peri, appreciate your input </cynicism>.

Comment: @Andrew: Am I wrong? People write as fast as they can because people posting questions accept not best but first answer.

Comment: I've edited to include the getter and setter properties, which syntactically is a better way to do it. I'm more concerned about the fact my answer was correct for what he asked for, but I'm not sure if it is anyones responsibility to tell people how to vote.

Comment: I suggest you read up and consider a singleton approach which is basically what this answer describes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Here u have create new class(Base class) which inherited from `Form` class like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class FormBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
   public List<string> MyList;
}
```

After that inherit all of ur form(3 forms) with this class like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Form")]
public partial class DeriveClass : FormBase
{
  private void Method()
  {
     base.MyList = new List<string>();
     // So something..
  }
}
```